# jquery setinterval cannot set interval time

Tags: jquery

got the following code :

```
$(setInterval(function()
            {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://uri/1/2', 
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false
            }).done(function(data){
            $('#show').text(data);
            }); 
            }
),3000);
```

Which doesn't seem to work properly. In Chrome the #show div is refreshed (or the ajax is executed) independantly of the interval defined in the setInterval function. In fact, if I set the time to 30000 (30s) I can see in the window that it does refresh almost instantly when adding new values into the database. In Firefox it simply doesn't seem to work. Adding new values to the database doesn't show on the page. Using the chrome dev tools I saw that the request were executing in less than a second and that after a while and because there were so many of them I would see in Network using devtools : net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES.

Has anyone encountered the same issue. Is it a bug or is it my code ?

Comment: What you're doing is executing an AJAX request every three seconds. Now the request may in fact take longer than three seconds (or less) so there's nothing that says your `#show` element will be updated every three seconds. It'll be every three seconds + the time it takes for the request to finish.

Comment: i believe `setInterval` will call the function immediately, then it will wait the amount of time specified to call it subsequent times

Comment: You're not actually passing `3000` to `setInterval()`. You're passing it as a second parameter to `$()`, and passing *no* timeout to `setInterval()`. Fix the last line, to `, 3000));`

Comment: You're right the last bracket made all the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have one too many brackets in the code, the 3000 doesn't appear to be sitting inside the setInterval function. Try this:

```
$(setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://uri/1/2', 
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false
    }).done(function(data){
        $('#show').text(data);
    }); 
},3000);
```